# How can I render a variable in a script that is in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I looked for a while to find a solution to this but I guess either I am not wording it right or maybe this solution isn't common.

Please see my below example:

```
    var someScript = '<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="" tag="vendorId" 
async="async"></scr'+'ipt>';
```

In the tag attribute, 'vendorId' is actually a variable that has a value.  How can I render the value of the variable rather than the key?

Comment: question is unclear. Render the value in script line or render the value through jquery you added as tag?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of string concatenation over here

You can do something like this:

```
var vendorId = '';//Need to pass in your value over here 
var someScript = '<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="" tag="'+vendorId+
  '" async="async"></scr'+'ipt>';
```